# Angular JS - load a templateUrl and controller on app initialization/beginning of app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

so I want to load a templateUrl or, invoke $stateProvider on an action other than user input, like onEnter or onload, or just right away at the beginning of the app, but I can't seem to figure it out.  Basically I have a simple nav, when clicked they load a partial which shows below the nav etc. I want to show an inital partial as soon as the app is invoked or loaded. below is a sample of my routing:

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

```
$stateProvider
 .state('page1', {
        url: "/page1",
        templateUrl: "partials/pag1.html"
    })
    .state('page1.stuff', {
        url: "/page1stuff",
        templateUrl: "partials/page1.stuff.html",
        controller: someController
    })
    .state('page2', {
        url: "/page2",
        templateUrl: "partials/page2.html"
    })
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: controller: someController should be  controller: 'someController'

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you just need a default state

```
.state('home', {
  url: '',
  templateUrl: 'partials/home.html'
}
```

Comment: yes but how does home get invoked at runtime? also my example code isn't exactly what I'm working with, basically I'm setting up the state's dynamically using a loop, i thought it would be a bit complicated to explain but here is the state portion of it: $stateProviderRef.state(theState, {
                url: theUrl,
                templateUrl: theTemplateUrl,
                controller: secondaryMenuCtrl
            })

Comment: The home state should be called because the url will be pointing to the root of your website e.g. url: ''. I don't follow you about how you are setting up the state dynamically. Set up a jsbin or something with your code if it doesn't work

Comment: alright so I made a plunkr I can't seem to create folders so it doesn't actually work but you can see what I have, I just want to load a partial at start up: http://plnkr.co/edit/4uFcVHvNXaj1Cgp2hdpe?p=preview

Comment: Seems overly complex but I guess yiou need to define your routes that way. I would either define a static home route (e.g. not as part fo the dynamic load) or I would add in the following check
    if(theState) theUrl = "/" + theState
    else theUrl = ''